# Not able to load node tree in umbraco 4.5.2 [Error. 500 Internal Server Error]

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

I am getting following error messagae , When I try to access respective tree node (umbraco 4.5.2)

> POST
>   .../umbraco/webservices/TreeClientService.asmx/GetInitAppTreeData
>
> 500 Internal Server Error
>         jquery.js?cdv=1 (line 130)

As following is the Image for the same.

[image]

I have also try by setting my IIS Application pool to Integrated Mode , but it's also did not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution.

Issue was in following folders. (Some file might be missng)

umbraco

umbraco_Client

So I have replaced both folder from fresh download umbraco.